# How do I have to configure vscode that pipenv and poetry venvs are supported in Python only projects?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to setup VSCode [MS Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) that when entering a folder (root dir of python only project, e.g. a Python package) which contains a [pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `Pipfile` the corresponding Python interpreter and environment shall be used. In case a folder contains a [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) `pyproject.toml` with `[tool.poetry]` sections however the corresponding virtual environment shall be used. I'm pretty sure one has to create the virtualenv in a subdir of the folder like e.g. `.venv` to make this work. Considering the github issues of [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) it's not clear to me if this setup can be configured at all and in case how. Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case one needs one Python venv in a single workspace only the solution is as follows:

- Add the folder `<some-path>/<project>` of the python project to a new window.
- Save workspace into the Python project root dir `<some-path>/<project>/<workspace>.code-workspace`. The content of `<workspace>.code-workspace` has to look like this:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

- Create the venv into `<some-path>/<project>/.venv`.

  - When using `pipenv` a specific venv location can be created by executing `python3 -m virtualenv -p python3 .venv` and `pipenv install`.
  - When using `poetry` execute `poetry config --local virtualenvs.in-project true` in `<some-path>/<project>`. This will create/update the `poetry.toml` with `[virtualenvs]\nin-project = true`. Run `poetry install` to create the venv. Previous venvs have to be deleted first of course.
- Set "Venv Path" in the workspace settings to `${workspaceFolder}/.venv`.
- Execute the "Python: Select Interpreter" (ctrl+shift+p, then command) and select the interpreter from the venv.

Answer (score 4):

Pipenv support for environments is built into the extension. You should only have to run the `Python: Select Interpreter` command and it should list your pipenv environment.

Poetry is not directly supported in the same way. You can upvote https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8372 to show your interest in the feature. But what you can do now is configure Poetry to create the virtual environment locally in your workspace and VS Code will pick that up automatically.

Comment: Missing support for poetry resulted in my decision to search for a solution which works independent of the actual venv management tool in use. The solution I came up with is working fine for me right now.